# Query ANTLR4 parse tree whether children were quantified in the grammar rule

Tags: parsing, antlr4

Having an ANTLR4 grammar, a matching input and a generated parse tree. Is there any way to find out about a node in the parse tree what kind of quantifier was applied to its definition if any?

An example: having a grammar like this:

start : 'a' ('b' | 'c')* 'd' ;

The input: 'abcd'

After parsing the input, the parse tree of 'start' rule will have 4 terminal children. The question is whether there is any way to find out about the second and third children ('b' and 'c') that they were optional?

Comment: the "optional" quantifier is part of your grammar. So whenever you see a 'b' or 'c' is matched, they're from an optional subrule. I don't understand your issue

Comment: Okay, there is some misunderstanding here. So, the goal is to find those parts in a matching input, that are not necessarily needed to stay syntactically correct, that's finding those parts whose quantifier was ?, * or perhaps +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to determine whether an optional subterm exists is to use a label

```
start : 'a' op+=('b' | 'c')* 'd' ;
```

This will result in the parse tree context `StartContext` having a field

```
List<TerminalNode> op;
```

If null, no `b` or `c` matched. Otherwise, `op` will contain a list of `b` and`c` instances in the order matched.

*Update*

Labeling would enable the parse tree structure to provide hints as to what subterms are optional, though even then the information would be incomplete.

Without labeling, the parse tree will only identify what is matched, and the order, but not any optional qualifier that may have been involved.

You could (1) parse the grammar itself, using [ANTLR's own grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr4), to directly determine the actual optional qualifiers applied to specific subterms; or (2) suitably fuzz the inputs and eventually deduce and qualify the optional subterms from whatever parse trees are cleanly generated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatelly I cannot alter the grammar (nor the test case to be parsed). The expectation is to work out a solution that receives an arbitrary grammar and a matching input and find all the parsetrees of the input that could have been omitted without causing a syntax error.

Comment: At the end I choose the ANTLR based solution: after identifying the optional rules in the target grammar, I mapped this information back to the parse tree with the help of visitors. If someone is interested, the implementation is available at https://github.com/renatahodovan/picireny/tree/master/picireny/antlr4 in the grammar_analyzer and hdd_tree_builder modules.